# Typescript build creates incorrect import path

Tags: typescript, tsc

When I run tsc.exe I end up with import paths that points to the source folder.

The files in dist/typescript-angular are generate by swagger-codegen with target language typescript-angular.

```
tsc -d --types node --target es5 --moduleResolution node --sourceMap true  --experimentalDecorators  --rootDir dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/ --outDir dist/node-models/fes_wecare_appointment/ dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/*.ts
```

I end up with imports from the source folder

```
export declare namespace WecareNewAppointment {
type AppointmentTypeEnum = 'video' | 'audio' | 'chat';
const AppointmentTypeEnum: {
    Video: import("../../../../../../../../../Users/x/projects/x/y/dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
    Audio: import("../../../../../../../../../Users/x/projects/x/y/dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
    Chat: import("../../../../../../../../../Users/x/projects/x/y/dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
};
```

}

there is no need too reference the slot type in the source folder. This is how it should look.

```
export declare namespace WecareNewAppointment {
type AppointmentTypeEnum = 'video' | 'audio' | 'chat';
const AppointmentTypeEnum: {
    Video: import("./slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
    Audio: import("./slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
    Chat: import("./slot").Slot.SlotTypeEnum;
};
```

}

Can I add a tsconfig or other hints to the tsc compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would definitely add tsconfig.json folder to your project root. and configure the following:

```
{
    "include": [
        "dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["node"],
        "outDir": "dist/node-models/fes_wecare_appointment/",
        "rootDir": "dist/typescript-angular/fes_wecare_appointment/model/",
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

then you jus run `tsc`

this makes it a bit clearer what you're trying to do. and it seems like your config is a little muddled since the included ts files and the js output are all in the same `dist` driectory. and it's unclear what the `rootDir` option is achieving? do you actually want `baseUrl`?

Also, how are you initially writing these imports in your ts files?

Comment: The files are generated by swagger-codegen. the failed import statements are generated by tsc.exe

Comment: sounds like the problem is in swagger. need to look at those ts files to be sure

Comment: Using your teconfig.json and running ts version 3.8.3 then everything works. Thanks